# AWS Lambda HTTPS Request - Blueprint

Tags: node.js, https, aws-lambda

I am bit new to AWS LAmbda and am trying to make an http request to a server through AWS Lambda function. I have used AWS HTTPS blueprint code and made only modification in `option` variable (see the code below).

```
const https = require('https');

let headers = {
    'Authorization': 'ApiKey {key}'
};

let options = {
    url: 'https://myds.io/api/external/patients/events/medications/',
    headers: headers
};

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        let body = '';
        console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('Successfully processed HTTPS response');
            // If we know it's JSON, parse it
            if (res.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json') {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
            }
            callback(null, body);
        });
    });
    req.on('error', callback);
    req.write(JSON.stringify(event.data));
    req.end();
};
```

When I am trying to run this code, I am getting the following error. I am not able to understand, where is the problem and what is wrong with the syntax. Request you to help me.

[image]

Just to invoke this Lambda function. I am using the following test function.

[image]

The following is the execution result.

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)",
    "_exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)",
    "TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)"
  ]
}

Request ID:
"0fae1df6-6351-11e8-9741-a3dc748f359b"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 0fae1df6-6351-11e8-9741-a3dc748f359b Version: $LATEST
2018-05-29T15:00:44.205Z    0fae1df6-6351-11e8-9741-a3dc748f359b    {"errorMessage":"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443","errorType":"Error","stackTrace":["Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)","_exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)","TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)"]}
END RequestId: 0fae1df6-6351-11e8-9741-a3dc748f359b
REPORT RequestId: 0fae1df6-6351-11e8-9741-a3dc748f359b  Duration: 35.27 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 22 MB
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is resolved now. I have made some edits in syntax and it works fine now.

```
'use strict'

const https = require('https');

let options = {
    host : 'myds.io',
    path:  '/api/external/patients/events/medications/',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'ApiKey *******'
        },
};

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        let body = '';
        console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('Successfully processed HTTPS response');
            // If we know it's JSON, parse it
            if (res.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json') {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
            }
            callback(null, body);
        });
    });
    req.on('error', callback);
    req.write(JSON.stringify(event.data));
    req.end();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `req.write(JSON.stringify(event.data));` it's seraching for `event.data` but your test event doesn't have a `data` key but just `key1, key2, key3`.

Try changing your test event to something similar to the following:

```
{
   "data": "something"
}
```

Comment: I have made edits in questions according to you suggestions. But the problem is not resolved yet. thoughts?

Comment: I have posted the code that works. Thank you so much for your time and suggestions!